# How can I change bootstrap 4 navbar toggler' color on hover?

Tags: css, bootstrap-4

I'm using Bootstrap 4 and I want my navbar toggle icon (known as the burger menu) to change color on `:hover` state.  This is what I've been trying but it won't work:

```
.navbar-light .navbar-toggler .menu-icon:hover,
.navbar-light .navbar-toggler .menu-icon:active,
.navbar-light .navbar-toggler .menu-icon:focus {
    color: red !important;
}
```

Here's my code:

```css
.navbar-light .navbar-toggler .menu-icon:hover,
.navbar-light .navbar-toggler .menu-icon:active,
.navbar-light .navbar-toggler .menu-icon:focus {
  color: red !important;
}
```

```html
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-white">
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.html">
    <img src="images/logo-paygol.svg" alt="Logo Paygol">
  </a>
  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarTopMenu" aria-controls="navbarTopMenu" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
      <span class="navbar-toggler-icon menu-icon"></span>
    </button></nav>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hey there as far as I know bootstrap 4 is using image `URL` to add the icon. This means it is an image and you can not add `hover` over an image. But there is a roundabout it.

So you must use a custom icon and add the hover for it as the following, am going to use fontawesome in this example.

```css
.navbar button.navbar-toggler:hover {
  color: red;
}


/* or 

.navbar .navbar-toggler span:hover i {
  color: red;
}

/*



/* 

or

.navbar .navbar-toggler span i:hover {
  color: red;
}
*/
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.14.0/css/all.min.css" integrity="sha512-1PKOgIY59xJ8Co8+NE6FZ+LOAZKjy+KY8iq0G4B3CyeY6wYHN3yt9PW0XpSriVlkMXe40PTKnXrLnZ9+fkDaog==" crossorigin="anonymous" />

<!-- CSS only -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-JcKb8q3iqJ61gNV9KGb8thSsNjpSL0n8PARn9HuZOnIxN0hoP+VmmDGMN5t9UJ0Z" crossorigin="anonymous">



<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
          <!-- <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span> -->
          <span><i class="fas fa-bars"></i></span>
        </button>

  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
    <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
      <li class="nav-item active">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item dropdown">
        <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                Dropdown
              </a>
        <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
          <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
        </div>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link disabled" href="#" tabindex="-1" aria-disabled="true">Disabled</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
    <form class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0">
      <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" type="search" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search">
      <button class="btn btn-outline-success my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit">Search</button>
    </form>
  </div>
</nav>

<!-- JS, Popper.js, and jQuery -->
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.1/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-9/reFTGAW83EW2RDu2S0VKaIzap3H66lZH81PoYlFhbGU+6BZp6G7niu735Sk7lN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-B4gt1jrGC7Jh4AgTPSdUtOBvfO8shuf57BaghqFfPlYxofvL8/KUEfYiJOMMV+rV" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

As you can see I did replace the icon bootstrap uses here

```
<span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
```

and I used mine from fontawesome as following

```
  <span><i class="fas fa-bars"></i></span>
```

and now the hover effects work since it is a font and you can change the color, and size very easily.

I hope that answers your question. If not do please let me know. and I will do my best to edit my answer to fit your question.